# variation of the Lieb concavity theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

A special case of the well known Lieb concavity theorem states that the following function is concave on positive operators A and B:

$$
(A,B) \to \text{Tr} \{A^s X B^{1-s} X^\dagger \}
$$

for $s \in [0,1]$ and an arbitrary operator $X$. I am wondering if it is known whether the following function is concave as well:

$$
(A,B) \to \text{Tr} \{A^s B^{(1-s)/2} X  X^\dagger B^{(1-s)/2} \}
$$

If not, do you have a counterexample? Apologies if this question has already been posted somewhere else in math overflow...

I have a similar question as the above one for the Ando convexity theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conjectured inequality is **false**.

Using cyclicity of the trace, let's first write it in a slightly nicer form
\begin{equation*}
 f(A,B) := \operatorname{tr}(X^*B^{(1-s)/2} A^sB^{(1-s)/2}X).
\end{equation*}

For joint-concavity to hold, we'd like to show
\begin{equation*}
 f\left(\tfrac{A+B}{2}, \tfrac{U+V}{2} \right) \ge \tfrac12f(A,U)+\tfrac12f(B,V).\qquad (*)
\end{equation*}

But picking $A,B,U,V,X$ as follows, we have an immediate counterexample (I used $s=0.5$):
\begin{equation*}
 A = \begin{pmatrix}  41 &  25\\ 25 & 26\end{pmatrix},\ 
 B = \begin{pmatrix}  2 &   7\\ 7 & 25\end{pmatrix},\ 
 U = \begin{pmatrix}  25 &  22\\ 22 & 20\end{pmatrix},\ 
 V = \begin{pmatrix}  5 &  5\\ 5 & 10\end{pmatrix},\\ 
 X = \begin{pmatrix}  1 &  0\\ 7 & -1\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

With this choice of variables, we obtain 5.964618e+03 < 6.529930e+03 in $(*)$ above.

---

### EDIT

In case you are interested or for others who may interested in concavity / convexity results similar in flavor to the one asked above, I'd like to mention the following nice paper: [*Concavity of certain matrix trace and norm functions*, F. Hiai (2013).](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.7524)

In that paper, Hiai studies (among others), joint concavity and convexity of maps of the form
\begin{equation*}
 (A,B) \mapsto \mbox{tr}(\Phi(A^p)^{1/2}\Psi(B^q)\Phi(A^p)^{1/2})^s,
\end{equation*}
for suitable choices of reals $p,q,s$, and positive linear maps $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ (e.g, with $\Phi(A) = X^*AX$, $\Psi=\mbox{Id}$, and $s=1$, we recover Lieb's concavity).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Since we know that it is true for $X = I$, is it possible to determine conditions on X such that the inequality is true?